# Why can't you build a RESTful API using data stored in a memory structure?

Tags: javascript, python, rest

I'm learning how to build APIs so that I can make simple interactive data visualizations in the client and pull data using get requests. The data source I'm using is about 12mb, so I thought I'd put it on a backend and make requests as needed.

I don't need PUT or DELETE, just GET. Found a lot of resources that show how to make very simple APIs using Python or Node, like [this one](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask), but in this guide, Miguel Grinburg says that you'll need a database as well:

> In place of a database we will store our task list in a memory structure. This will only work when the web server that runs our application is single process and single threaded. This is okay for Flask's own development web server. It is not okay to use this technique on a production web server, for that a proper database setup must be used.

Is this strictly true? What are the consequences of storing data in a memory structure? I don't wholly understand what he means by "single threaded" and "single process" either.

Comment: No, that's not strictly true, if the entire dataset is just 12mb, keeping it in memory isn't an issue, but you'll have to store it somewhere else as well, for instance in a file, so you can load it again when the server crashes (and it will).

Comment: If you store it in memory, you have to arrange for all the server processes to be able to access that memory. And like @adeneo says, you have to save it across crashes. As far as the protocol is concerned, it doesn't matter how you implement the server. It's mostly a matter of practicality.

Comment: @adeneo, yes keeping it in a file is no problem. My idea is that the backend would read and parse the file into some various chunks and then serve those chunks up on different routes. 

Is my server more likely to crash b/c it is holding a 12mb file in memory? Or are you just saying that crashes are generally inevitable and that

Comment: @Barmar so are you saying it's more of a performance thing? That is, filtering through a 12mb in memory is going to be less performant than a database call, and that makes sense to me. But I guess the question is, would a set up like that choke with many users accessing it? Or just be a little less performant in general?

Comment: All servers crash, or are shut down at some point, you have to be able to load the data into memory when the webserver starts up, but it's not going to crash because you store something in memory. Getting data from memory is fast, and a database will store the data on disk or in memory anyway, it just abstracts away the persistency and makes it easier to query the data, but storing a 12mb object directly in Node is probably as fast as you'll get it, and is doable and not really an issue if that's what you want to do.

Comment: @user1502186 Performance of memory will be very good. I'm saying that it would be harder to implement a memory-based server, because most existing software is not designed around that type of architecture. So you'll have to create it all from scratch instead of being able to use off-the-shelf solutions.